# Alternative to Protobuf for size

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-csharp-port

I have recently taken on a task where it was suggested to use Protobuf to serialize an object to be written out as a base64 string. This would be protobuf-net at the moment for the .NET port. The prior methods of storing this data was a series of bit masking but that has been outgrown and this was the suggested route. Unfortunately the data written out from this approach is simply too large for my purposes.

In code the object that I am serializing looks like this. I've tried both using decorated POCOs and generated classes by ProtoGen. ProtoGen generated classes actually serialized into less optimized data.

```
Obj
  - Time
  - List of an objects. A pair is what must be recorded.
      Pair = [Key | Time]
```

Looking at the output and the way the size grows as the list length grows I'm thinking some of the size is coming from storing type information about the class type. I tried to see how this would go with storing the pairs in parallel arrays and using "Packed" however I'm not seeing much a size improvement. Maybe 10%-15%. As it stands this is an order of magnitude larger than the previous method of data storage however that old method won't work as we are running out of key space.

My question is, besides simply making the key space larger by adding a few more bits here in the old method, is there a way to optimize Protobuf for size that I may be missing? Or perhaps an alternative for serializing rather simple objects optimized for size?

I haven't tried it yet, but from what I'm reading, even GZipping the current data would only return marginal improvements. I'll be benching that as an option next.

Sample class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo : BaseOfFoo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public UInt32 Time { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<ValuePair> KeywordValues { get; private set; }
}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class ValuePair
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public UInt32 Id { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public UInt32 Time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: if you are converting to a B64 string, why use a binary serializer?    How is it used?

Comment: What you are saying doesn't add up, Protobuf stores very minimal type data, and other than serializing the data manually, I can't think of a more minimalistic approach. Please show relevant code.

Comment: @Plutonix What do you mean exactly? How would you get the bytes to feed into the B64 string otherwise?

Comment: the question is how are you using the output?  *why* does it need to be a base64 string?  what happens to the B64 string?  that conversion is what is bloating the size

Comment: @Plutonix The previous storage also was base64'd. Its being used in cookie data.

Comment: @Rotem It definitely is storing type data according to Google. Their documentation indicates that it does. The Packed option is only available for simple data which then doesn't store type meta data for each object in the collection.

Comment: @Rig I didn't say it doesn't store type data, I said the type data is very small compared to what is saved by other serialization frameworks. Until you show how you're decorating your classes and serializing, this is guesswork.

Comment: Protocol buffers stores the wire type as 3 bits. Provided the protocol buffers field numbers are < 32, there is a 1 byte overhead per field in the binary format. The Field number is combined with the wire-type.

Comment: Can you provide the definitions. You can waste space in protocol buffers if you use wrong Type

Comment: Added some sample code. I've also tried declaring it as a proto file and generating code as well as playing with the data types some.